# Prints value when clicked on but line isn't created?

Tags: python, events, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm currently learning the matplotlib library on python 3.4. I'm practicing on a code where the user is supposed to interact with the plot only by clicking on it. When the click happens somewhere on the plot two things are supposed to happen: print out the y value and create a horizontal line in the plot where the click happened.

What I'm getting when I click somewhere on the plot is that the print happens as desired but the horizontal line shows up only if I press F (which fulls screen the plot). In other words, the line is created when I click on the plot but it doesn't appear untill I press F. Any ideas why it's happening?

The code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))

def pick(event):
    plt.hlines(event.ydata,event.xdata-
    0.2,event.xdata+0.2,colors='r',linestyle='solid')
    print('Y coord = %f'%event.ydata)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',pick)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [interactive mode](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ion) to update the plot after each click. Use plt.ion() before plt.show().

Comment: Using it before the plt.show() caused the plot to not showing up. But when I put it as the first line of the pick(event) func it worked fine. Thanks.